# Organizing WinForm Controls Code

Tags: c#, .net

What is the ideal way to organize the code for form controls when using WinForms? This sounds ambiguous, let me expand to add clarity.

My application uses a number of form controls. ListView is one of them. Before the app launches I have to set the headers of the ListView, andd the columns, grab the data, populate the ListView etc. Not only that there is also the code to redraw the list view when items are removed or adding, and also various code for events on the ListView.

This is one example. My application uses a number of controls that have a lot of functionality and require setting up prior to loading or redrawing at run time.

To stuff all this into the main Form would just get complex and messy.

What are ideal options for keeping things clean, tidy and maintainable?

Comment: Create a constructor for the form controls ,and handle the functionality from the constructor. Or hanlde the functionality in form_load event of the form that contains the control.

Comment: Unclear: is this a question about code layout or about multithreaded control initialization?

Comment: Edited post, I see where the confusion could have came from.

Answer (score 2):

If you were looking for element ordering rather than a design pattern then I suggest [Style Cop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/). After you get used to it, it makes finding the code you want much easier. (Style Cop has many other rules regarding commenting etc, which also make code organisation much easier).

According to style cop element ordering rules http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1201.html elements should be placed in the following order:

- Extern Alias Directives
- Using Directives
- Namespaces
- Delegates
- Enums
- Interfaces
- Structs
- Classes

Within a class, struct, or interface, elements must be positioned in the following order:

- Fields
- Constructors
- Finalizers (Destructors)
- Delegates
- Events
- Enums
- Interfaces
- Properties
- Indexers
- Methods
- Structs
- Classes

**Edit**
Since the OP's last edit I see this is not *really* what he's talking about.
I'd recommend moving all code not directly related to user interface into another class, or multiple classes and only keep the code that directly references UI controls in the Form class.

Comment: +1 for mentioning StyleCop...I use it as it's helped me to document my framework, and keep it organised, but IMO it's overly anal with it's organisation rules

Comment: Agreed, but I certainly find it much easier to find what I'm looking for now I use Style Cop than the time before!

Comment: Likewise, however I have adjusted my stylecop rules as I prefer a different layout to what StyleCop tries to enforce, for classes/structs I prefer: constants/readonly fields, fields, properties, constructors, finalizers, operator methods, static methods, instance methods, events/delegates, inner types...just a personal preference. In addition to this, I have a pre-defined template for organising code, which uses regions - This makes organisation real easy, and I always know where I should be looking.

Comment: Each to his own - the point is you know where your code is. I region my code too, but haven't got a template... good plan. Might set one up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use design patterns such as:

Model–view–presenter (MVP);

Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM);

Model–view–controller (MVC).

They are great for separating the logic layer from the user interface layer. You can see some examples [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained). This one is for Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) and works for me.

The good thing about design patterns is that they make your code testable.

Comment: OP asks how to organize UI.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of patterns that you may use to modularize your code. A popular way of populating your GUI with data is using an MVC or MVP paradigms. If you need to get your data without blocking your UI thread then you can use `delegates` in your Presenter/Controllerto retrieve necessary data from your underlying datasource(s).

Answer (score 0):

Create a `constructor` for the form controls ,and handle the functionality from the constructor. Or hanlde the functionality in `form_load` event of the form that contains the control